# NinjectModule and IProvider not resolving types

Tags: ninject

Here is the set up that is not working
Using Ninject V3.0

```
public class LoggerModule : NinjectModule{
public override void Load()
{
 Bind<ILogger>.ToProvider(MyLoggerProvider);
}
}

public class MyLoggerProvider: IProvider<ILogger>
{
 public object Create(IContext context){
return new OneOfMyLoggers();
}
}
```

In my application wherever I inject instance of ILogger (using constructor or property injection, just does matter) I never get instance of ILogger resolved.

But If do not use module and/or povider, and bind when kernel is created, everything works like a charm. The following works

```
public class MyDiResolver()
{
  public MyDiResolver()
{
  MyKernel = new StandardKernel();
  MyKernel.Bind<ILogger>().To<OneOfMyLoggers>();
}
}
```

The same arrangement of modules and providers works fine in Ninject2.x version. Is there something different about Ninject V3.0 that I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the module into the StandardKernel so it knows to use it:

```
using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new LoggerModule()))
{
    ILogger logger = kernel.Get<OneOfMyLoggers>();   
}
```

Comment: I just did not type that part of the code. The module is passed in constructor of Kernel.